# MySQL inner join alias issue

Tags: mysql, join, alias

I am trying to write an sql join but I'm getting a not unique error:

```
SELECT matches.match_id, 
       teamsh.team_name  AS "homeTeam", 
       teamsh.team_id    AS "homeID", 
       teamsa.team_name  AS "awayTeam", 
       teamsa.team_id    AS "awayID", 
       competition.NAME, 
       competition.competition_id, 
       teamsh.stadium, 
       matches.date, 
       teamsh.name_short AS "homeTeamShort", 
       teamsa.name_short AS "awayTeamShort", 
       teamsh.pysioid    AS "pysioIDh", 
       teamsa.pysioid    AS "pysioIDa" 
FROM   matches, 
       teams teamsh, 
       teams teamsa, 
       competition

INNER JOIN
teamsh ON matches.home_team_id = teamh.team_id,
teamsa ON matches.away_team_id = teama.team_id,
competition ON matches.competition_id = competition.competition_id ​

WHERE  match_id = 22268
```

## 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'teamsh'.

I know i'm close but the alias has beaten me.

Thank you in advance,

Al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing old-style joins with proper join syntax:

```
SELECT matches.match_id, 
       teamsh.team_name  AS "homeTeam", 
       teamsh.team_id    AS "homeID", 
       teamsa.team_name  AS "awayTeam", 
       teamsa.team_id    AS "awayID", 
       competition.NAME, 
       competition.competition_id, 
       teamsh.stadium, 
       matches.date, 
       teamsh.name_short AS "homeTeamShort", 
       teamsa.name_short AS "awayTeamShort", 
       teamsh.pysioid    AS "pysioIDh", 
       teamsa.pysioid    AS "pysioIDa" 
FROM   matches
INNER JOIN
teams AS teamsh ON matches.home_team_id = teamsh.team_id
INNER JOIN 
teams AS teamsa ON matches.away_team_id = teamsa.team_id
INNER JOIN
competition ON matches.competition_id = competition.competition_id ​
WHERE  match_id = 22268
```

You were getting the error because `teamsh` and `teamsa` were used multiple times as table names/aliases.

Comment: thanks for the replies. I'm now getting #1054 - Unknown column 'matches.competition_id' in 'on clause'. competition_id exists in the matches table so the error message doesn't help

Comment: @AlanA That seems odd, is the above the full query you're using? The most common cause for this error when the field exists is mixing old-style joins with ANSI joins, but we've removed those from the query above, so it's curious.

Comment: here is the exact sql I am using: https://gist.github.com/spacebiscuit/be0f8eb07e35b2e029e9 - Not unique table/alias: 'competition'

Comment: @AlanA Yeah, in that query you're still using a comma separated list to join tables, you need to get rid of `,'teams','competition'`

Comment: @GotaCO see the update: https://gist.github.com/spacebiscuit/be0f8eb07e35b2e029e9 - check syntax to use near '`teamsa`.`pysioid` AS 'pysioIDa' 
FROM matches
INNER JOIN
`teams` `teamsh` ON `ma' at line 13

Comment: @AlanA You just need to change the `ON` criteria, once you alias a table you use the alias from then on to reference it:
`INNER JOIN 'teams' 'teamsh' ON 'matches'.'team_id' = 'teamsh'.'team_id'
INNER JOIN 'teams' 'teamsa' ON 'matches'.'team_id' = 'teamsa'.'team_id'`

Comment: Got it working now with: https://gist.github.com/spacebiscuit/be0f8eb07e35b2e029e9 Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `FROM` clause. It should look like this:

```
FROM  matches
INNER JOIN
teams teamsh ON matches.home_team_id = teamh.team_id
INNER JOIN
teams teamsa ON matches.away_team_id = teama.team_id
INNER JOIN
competition ON matches.competition_id = competition.competition_id ​
```

Comment: close but `teamh` and `teama` aren't the table alias names need an `s` in there.

Comment: @dan08 - thanks, it give me unknown column 'matches.competition_id' in 'on clause'.